# Google Analytics Dataset Mapping

Tags: list, scala, google-analytics, mapping, filtering

I have a dataset from Google Analytics I have a hard time mapping to something useful that I can use in production.

The raw data is a list of case class objects looking like this:

```
case class Stats(id: String, date: Int, pViews: Int, uViews: Int)
```

I have gone about making the list of objects like this:

```
val skuMatch = "[A-Z][0-9]{10}".r
val mappedRaw = rawData
  .map(row => {
    val idCheck = idMatch.findFirstIn(row.getDimensions()(1))
    val id = if (idCheck.isDefined) idCheck.get else ""
    val date = row.getDimensions()(0).toInt
    val pViews = row.getMetrics()(0).getValues()(0).toInt
    val uViews = row.getMetrics()(0).getValues()(1).toInt
    Stats(id, date, pViews, uViews)
  }).filter(!_.id.isEmpty)
}
```

So now I have a list of objects that are "clean" so no empty dirty, values. An object might look like this:

```
Stats("A0000000008", 201608, 10, 1)
```

Now, the list contains multiple objects with the same `id` value because they then have a different `date` value or they might be valid duplicates where the `pViews` and `uViews` data is still relevant.

```
Stats("A0000000008", 201609, 12, 5)
Stats("A0000000008", 201609, 8, 2)
```

My question therefore is, how do I make a structure that looks like this:

```
case class DataMonth(monthYear: Int, uViews: Int, pViews: Int)
case class NewStats(id: String, months: List(DataMonth))
```

Example object:

```
List(
    NewStats(
        "A0000000008",
        List(
            DataMonth(
                201608,
                10,
                1
            ),
            DataMonth(
                201609,
                20,
                7
            )
        )
    )
)
```

So that it has taken all the duplicates grouped the data by months aka. the date value.

I have a really hard time wrapping my head around these kinds of problems so I would be grateful for any kind of help really.
Thanks in advance.